# No resource available for a spark submitted script on a remote cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am requesting a server with Spark installed on it from an other server without spark (just PySpark is installed on the second server).

When I launch this command, on the second server:

```
bin/spark-submit --master spark://<ip_server_1>:7077 src/remote-spark/init.py
```

It seems to work according to the Spark Master GUI page: a session have been created.

However the user who created the Spark session is named from the second server. This is not the server 1 user who usually creates the Spark session on the server.
So I cannot access the Stages for all jobs GUI page and I get this information:

```
2019-05-02 08:18:57 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(<user_server_2>); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(<user_server_2>); groups with modify permissions: Set()
```

Moreover, when I want to execute the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("remoteSpark") \
    .master("spark://<ip_server_1>:7077") \
    .config("spark.cores.max", 2) \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.range(10)
df.sample(0.5, 3).count()
```

I get this information :

```
TaskSchedulerImpl:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

But I have checked and I have enough resources.

P.S.: I have tried to submit the script with the parameter `--deploy-mode cluster` but currently *Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters*

Comment: Indeed it is the same issue... so now I have to figure out how to avoid the cluster deploy mode with python

Comment: This resource helped me to understand the deploy structure:
https://becominghuman.ai/real-world-python-workloads-on-spark-standalone-clusters-2246346c7040